# WIX: how to specify different text on exit dialog for repair and remove?

Tags: wix

I'm using WIX 3.0

After I install my product, I can run installer again and remove or repair my product.

How to specify different text on exit dialog for repair and remove?

I used "Installed" property, but it has the same value for repair and remove

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for update, Yan.

My problem was not how to change some text, but how to know what action was performed, remove or repair.

I don't know if this is good solution, but I used custom action and set the all text I need in the properties. The custom action runs with condition $MyInstalledComponent=2, which means that component is removed and is TRUE only on remove, but not on repair

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the ExitDialog.wxs for this (taking it from WiX sources and including to your project).

Take ProgressDlg.wxs as an example. It contains several pairs of controls, prefixed with 'Text' and 'Title', for instance 'TextInstalling' and 'TitleInstalling'. These pairs of controls are located at the same positions on a dialog, but are conditioned differently. For instance, 'TextRemoving' and 'TitleRemoving' are shown when WixUI_InstallMode='Remove'. Hence, setting WixUI_InstallMode to 'Remove' at the beginning of uninstall shows "Removing files", etc. on a progress dialog.

You can use this technique for other dialogs as well.